# Assist Ivy to know that two artifacts with distinct org are the same

Tags: maven, ant, ivy

In my Ivy project, different transitive dependencies depend on the same package: [javassist](http://www.javassist.org/). Unfortunately the packer hasn't been consistent with the `org` definition (`groupId` in Maven terms). For instance:

- version 3.5.GA has org="org.jboss",
- version 3.12.GA has org="javassist"
- version 3.13.GA has org="org.javassist"

Ivy does not identify these as the same dependency, and retrieve all versions.

Question: what is the best way to instruct Ivy that javassist packages, with either of the `org` definitions above, refer to the same dependency?

### UPDATE

I added simplified versions of the Ivy files that illustrate the doubt
*ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="org.myorg" module="mymodule" revision="latest"/>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="5.2.16.Final" force="true"/>
    <dependency org="org.jboss" name="jboss-retro" rev="1.1.0" force="true"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

*ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="mychain"/>
  <caches>
    <cache name="mycache" defaultTTL="1d"/>
  </caches>
  <resolvers checkModified="true">
    <chain name="mychain" cache="mycache">
      <ibiblio name="myreleases" m2compatible="true" usepoms="true" root="https://repo.local/release/"/>
      <ibiblio name="mysnapshot" m2compatible="true" usepoms="true" root="https://repo.local/snapshot"/>
     </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The following is the [dependency tree](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/dependencytree.html) generated by Ivy:

```
Dependency tree for org.myorg.mymodule
+- org.hibernate#hibernate-core;5.2.16.Final
|  +- org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.3.1.Final
|  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.1-api;1.0.0.Final
|  +- org.javassist#javassist;3.22.0-GA
|  +- antlr#antlr;2.7.7
|  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction#jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec;1.0.1.Final
|  +- org.jboss#jandex;2.0.3.Final
|  +- com.fasterxml#classmate;1.3.0
|  +- dom4j#dom4j;1.6.1
|  \- org.hibernate.common#hibernate-commons-annotations;5.0.1.Final
|  |  +- org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.3.1.Final
|     \- org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.3.0.Final
\- org.jboss#jboss-retro;1.1.0
|  +- jboss#jboss-backport-concurrent;2.1.0.GA
|  +- org.jboss#javassist;3.5.GA
|  \- org.apache.ant#ant;1.7.0
|     \- org.apache.ant#ant-launcher;1.7.0
```

Notice that `hibernate-core` depends on `org.javassist#javassist;3.22.0-GA`, and `jboss-retro` depends on `org.jboss#javassist;3.5.GA`. Both are different versions of the same dependency. However, Ivy cannot identify that since they have different `org` entries.

Comment: Could you please add your ivy.xml and ivysettings.xml to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with [namespaces](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/namespaces.html). These are regular expression-based mappings of different `org`, `module` and `rev` to a common naming.

The following configuration fixed the issue above. Here, `<tosystem>` defines the mapping from an external repository to the local (system) namespace (including the local Ivy cache at `~/.ivy2/cache`).

```
<namespace name="mynamespace">
  <rule>
    <fromsystem/>
    <tosystem>
      <src org="org.jboss" module="javassist"/>
      <src org="javassist" module="javassist"/>
    <dest org="org.javassist" module="javassist"/>
    </tosystem>
  </rule>
</namespace>
```

The issue with the solution above is with Ivy cache. It is not updated with the new namespace definition.

In the example, the ivy file for jboss-retro, generated from the downloaded POM file, still lists `org.jboss#javassist` as a dependency since the namespace mapping wasn't in place when it was downloaded. Moreover, since the POM file doesn't change at the external repository, the cache isn't invalidated.

So far the alternatives to regenerate the ivy file are either to manually delete the cache entries that are affected by the new rule (which isn't trivial), or to [clean the whole cache](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) (which might take long to recreate)